# C# how to protect the field of an atomic class?

Tags: c#, concurrency, atomic, atomicreference

I'm trying to make an AtomicReference class in C# and I want to keep the field reference protected, but I also need to return the value in the get method:

```
class AtomicReference
{
    private Object _value;

    public AtomicReference()
    {
        _value = new Object();
    }

    public AtomicReference(Object value)
    {
        OptimisticSet(value);
    }

    public Object CompareAndSet(Object newValue)
    {
        return Interlocked.Exchange(ref _value, newValue);
    }

    public void OptimisticSet(Object newValue)
    {
        do { 
        } while (_value == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _value, _value, newValue));
    }

    public Object Get()
    {
        // Don't leak the field reference
        const Object constVal = _value;
        return constVal;
    }
}
```

It's a bit of a clumsy way around the problem... I can't make the field readonly, because I need to be able to set it.  Is there a better solution than mine?

UPDATE:
Thanks for the quick responses!
It was rightfully pointed out that the reference will be protected if I simply return _value.  I also want to protect the _value from mutating.  If I allow the _value to mutate outside of the AtomicReference, then it defeats the entire purpose of making this class... is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Why is there a java tag?

Comment: The java tag meaning that I want to get similar functionality to Java's AtomicReference.

Comment: By the way, you should make it a generic class.

Comment: I've struggled with the generic class idea, too... in particular the fact that _value is of type T, and I can't use the operator== on _value.

Comment: If you add a ` where T : class` constraint to the class definition, you'll be able to use the `==` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you try, it is not possible to return a reference to a field in C# (without unsafe code) or Java.  (I don't mean a reference to an object)

You can simply write `return _value;` your callers will not be able to write to the field.

Comment: True that callers cannot change _value itself to refer to a different object, but won't callers be able to mutate the object that _value refers to? For example, if object is really of type Square, callers will be able to do `obj.Side++`. My understanding of the question is that he wishes to avoid such mutations.

Comment: If so, he's out of luck; that's not possible to do. (Unless you restrict to value types or `IClonable`)  From the fact that he accepted the answer, I _assume_ that he isn't.

Comment: Yeah I re-read the sample and it looks like he only cares about the references.

Comment: Not possible to do? Do I have to clone the object? A constant won't do it? What's the solution?

Comment: @Link: What exactly are you trying to do? If you don't want people to make the `_value` field point to a different object (like Java's `AtomicReference`), you're fine.  If you don't want the object that `_value` points to to change at all, it's not possible.

Comment: @SLaks
OK... I understand now.  For some reason I was thinking that if I pass an integer I will be able to protect it.  That is a completely different concept that is solved by the AtomicInteger class.  Sorry for giving you the run-around! I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

C# does not support C++'s `const` keyword, which allows for immutable references to mutable objects.

There are only two ways to do what you're asking.

- You could clone the object whenever you return it.  Note that this will only work for clonable objects, and it'll be quite slow.
- You could only support value types.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry, I was inadvertently thinking of two separate ideas... I was thinking of passing an Int32/Int64 to the AtomicReference class, completely blanking out that the proper way to do it is with an AtomicInteger.